# Check if -[NSData writeToFile:atomically:] is done

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, file-io, nsdata

```
-(void)WriteToFile:(NSString*)fileName andString:(NSString*)array{
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt",fileName]];
    NSData *serializedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
    [serializedData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

I have a big `NSString` that I want to write to a text file. How do I check if it is already done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-[NSData writeToFile:atomically:]` doesn't return until the write has either completed or failed. Until control passes back to your code, the operation is still running.

Check the returned `BOOL` to see if the write has succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the answer. your answers in many different questions has helped me a lot, :D could this work now? based on what i want to do? :D

-(BOOL)WriteToFile:(NSString*)fileName andString:(NSString*)array{
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt",fileName]];
    NSData *serializedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
    [serializedData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
return YES;
}

ps. i dont know how to highlight code in comment section. XD

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but `return [serializedData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; }` would make more sense to me.

Comment: oh so my original code would already work? because as you said, it would not go to the next line without completing?

Comment: That's correct. Your own method will not finish until `writeToFile:atomically:` has returned.